# ASP.NET master page inherit error

Tags: asp.net

I think I have a fairly simple question. I'm just starting a web app with asp.net and i wanted to use a master page. However, after creating it and trying to run it with some sample code I get this error:

Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).

Source Error:

```
Line 12: namespace MvcApplication3
Line 13: {
Line 14:     public partial class Site : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
Line 15:     {
Line 16:         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

My Site.Master file has what I think is the correct inherit call:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.Master.cs" Inherits="Site" %>
```

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Well your MasterPage isn't inheriting the `Site` class, it's the opposite.

Comment: *MvcApplication3* and *Page_Load* event? O_o

Comment: @Shimrod That's not true. The specific master page inherits the class that's in its codebehind, which in turn inherits `System.Web.UI.MasterPage`. Same for pages and controls - the inheritance chain generally goes those three levels (`ASP.site_master : MyApp.Site : System.Web.UI.MasterPage`)

Comment: The code I posted is pretty much what you get if you create a new Master page in VS, so I assumed it would work unless my namespace is screwing it up

Comment: Thanks @JoeEnos, I didn't knew that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're just missing the namespace at the header your master page:

```
<%@ Master ... CodeFile="Site.Master.cs" Inherits="MvcApplication3.Site" %>
```

Comment: Without the namespace in the `Inherits` line, I get your error. As soon as I add it, it compiles and runs perfectly. Your class is in the same directory as the master page, and is named `Site.Master.cs`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Are you intended on "public partial class Site" to itself be a master page?  It seems you're adding a level between the page and the master page that doesn't need to be there.

My page classes use the following syntax to specify a master page.

```
MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" 
Inherits="namespace.pageClassName"
```

You can have a custom page class that acts as a base class for the Page class, but I've never seen anyone sub-class a master page like that.

Comment: Aside from the namespace confusion, the question shows exactly the out-of-the-box master page. The `.master` file has an `Inherits` attribute - it inherits from a class which in turn inherits from `System.Web.UI.MasterPage`.